# Anime/cartoon? - redhaired kid in yellow jacket fights monster with a magic glove that dispenses food

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

When I was young, I used to watch this anime/cartoon, but all I can remember about it is that there is a small kid wearing a yellow jacket without sleeves, whose hair was red. He fights monsters by using his magical glove which, when activated,  dispenses food (e.g., red chili, cherries) and then the boy eats the food with chopsticks, and then he gets powers. I don't remember how.

And I think there was a big white "dog" with long ears with the kid helping him with his adventure.

Comment: Consider having a look at [_"How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?"_](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/40711) for a checklist that could help you remember further details to narrow down the search.

Comment: Possibly related, since there is a kid who gets animal powers from what he ate with chopsticks, and is involved in combat: [Animated series whose main character wears a red gauntlet on his arm](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/193796/98028)

Answer (score 3):

The answer to [Animated series whose main character wears a red gauntlet on his arm](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193796/animated-series-whose-main-character-wears-a-red-gauntlet-on-his-arm) matches to this question.

*[ChaeChaepong Kimchipong](https://myanimelist.net/anime/37798/ChaeChaepong_Kimchipong)*.

[image: Image of protagonist with mons]

> In the most peaceful village on Earth, Singleland, a boy named Tochi lives a normal life with his grandmother. One day, all the creatures that lived in their land are suddenly petrified, leaving Tochi as the lone survivor.
>
> Bewildered and frightened, Tochi meets a travelling little witch named Milo who informs him that what happened to his village, and many other villages including her own was due to the curse of the Black Mage Army. She reveals that he wasn't petrified because he had the magical Kimchi Stalks, therefore she gives him the "Chae Chong", a summoning tool, which only the person with Kimchi Stal can own. The "Chae Chong" can summon a Kimchi Pong when you put a Kimchi Stall, a powerful magical creature, which they use to fight the Black Army.
>
> The story follows as Tochi and Milo travel the world in search of new Kimchi Pong to save their homes and uncover the secrets behind these creatures.

An image of the protagonist with his "Chae Chong":
[image: Tochi eating kimchee on his "Chae Chong"]

### Anime Opening

Comment: Always useful, although I'd have offered to the other answerer to answer it themselves

Comment: You have a point. I will yield if they wish.