# Animated series whose main character wears a red gauntlet on his arm

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

The main character has a gauntlet or a similar gadget in his arm that summons different creatures either for combat or just as companions, and also a yo-yo that he uses in combat and infuses it with the power of the summoned creatures.

To activate the animal's powers he ate food that shared similarities with the animal in question. For example, to activate a cubic-shaped bird's powers he ate a marshmallow. He used chopsticks so it might have been from an Asian country.

The sidekick (a girl if I remember correctly) has another gadget that she uses to collect artifacts that they encounter on their journey (either an accordion or a book).

The names of the creatures might have been awfully translated from the original version but in the version I watched it in (Arabic) it goes something like: booboo deedee....

It aired on MBC3 somewhere between 2005 and 2012.

Comment: Hi there! :) there's already good info in there, but maybe you could take a look at [this guide on how to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, was that rather a cartoon (Western-style animation) or an anime (Asian-style animation)? When did you watch it, do you remember the channel it was aired on? Stuff like that, to increase the chances of a successful ID. Cheers!

Comment: I don't see yo-yos, but you could take a look at the answers of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/184657/98028) about an anime featuring the summoning of creatures, and which was aired on MBC3 circa 2010.

Comment: Thanks for redirecting me to these useful links, Jenayah. Unfortunately the answers are not what i'm looking for

Comment: You should check [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MBC_3) and see if you recognize anything.

Comment: i did, the show i'm looking for isn't mentioned. i checked every show to make sure it wasn't the one

Answer (score 4):

After doing a thorough search,  think I found it, it's called *[ChaeChaepong Kimchipong](https://myanimelist.net/anime/37798/ChaeChaepong_Kimchipong)*.

[image: Image of protagonist with mons]

> In the most peaceful village on Earth, Singleland, a boy named Tochi lives a normal life with his grandmother. One day, all the creatures that lived in their land are suddenly petrified, leaving Tochi as the lone survivor.
>
> Bewildered and frightened, Tochi meets a travelling little witch named Milo who informs him that what happened to his village, and many other villages including her own was due to the curse of the Black Mage Army. She reveals that he wasn't petrified because he had the magical Kimchi Stalks, therefore she gives him the "Chae Chong", a summoning tool, which only the person with Kimchi Stal can own. The "Chae Chong" can summon a Kimchi Pong when you put a Kimchi Stall, a powerful magical creature, which they use to fight the Black Army.
>
> The story follows as Tochi and Milo travel the world in search of new Kimchi Pong to save their homes and uncover the secrets behind these creatures.

An image of the protagonist with his "Chae Chong":
[image: Tochi eating kimchee on his "Chae Chong"]

### Anime Opening

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you the same person as the one who originally asked the question? Also, one is generally expected to describe or quote the contents of a link instead of just providing a link.

Comment: OMG i had forgotten about this post i wrote this is exactely what i was looking for thaaanks