# Old cartoon where villain turns villagers into statues

Tags: story-identification, anime

I used to watch a cartoon as a kid where a villain turns villagers into stone statues and there is a kid from that village that has a cylindrical object where he can insert balls that contain monsters in them.

There was a wolf that I remember, and in the last episode they summon a woman warrior with a sword. They defeat the main villain and turns all the villagers back to normal, there is a girl too that tags along with him...

I have been looking for this cartoon for years now.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! First of all, since you tagged this question with [tag:anime] but state in the body as "cartoon", is this a (Western) cartoon, or a (Japanese/Asian) anime? Around what time/year is "as a kid"? Also, consider consulting [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874) and see if there are more details you can add. If so, you can always [edit] your question to improve it!

Comment: sorry this is literally my first time here , and i think it was an anime , i watched it around 2008-2009 when i was like 8 years old , the boy had a cylindrical red object that he attached to his hand , and he would put balls that contains monster in them to summon the monsters ... thats all i remember

Comment: Do you recall who the characters looked,  like hair color, clothing, or items that may help identify. Or a tv channel

Answer (score 2):

Probably *Chaechaepong Kimchipong*, a 2002 Korean anime. I remember it being the answer to [Animated series whose main character wears a red gauntlet on his arm](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/193796/) (the "cylindrical object​ on his arm" is what reminded me of it).

Summary from that link:

> In the most peaceful village on Earth, Singleland, a boy named Tochi lives a normal life with his grandmother. **One day, all the creatures that lived in their land are suddenly petrified, leaving Tochi as the lone survivor.**
>
> Bewildered and frightened, **Tochi meets a travelling little witch named Milo** who informs him that what happened to his village, and many other villages including her own was due to the curse of the Black Mage Army. She reveals that he wasn't petrified because he had the magical Kimchi Stalks, therefore **she gives him the "Chae Chong", a summoning tool**, which only the person with Kimchi Stal can own. The "Chae Chong" can summon a Kimchi Pong when you put a Kimchi Stall, a powerful magical creature, which they use to fight the Black Army.

[This wiki](https://namu.wiki/w/%EC%B1%84%EC%B1%84%ED%90%81%20%EA%B9%80%EC%B9%98%ED%90%81#s-4.1) (Google-translated [here](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=2&sl=ko&tl=en&u=https://namu.wiki/w/%25EC%25B1%2584%25EC%25B1%2584%25ED%2590%2581%2520%25EA%25B9%2580%25EC%25B9%2598%25ED%2590%2581&xid=17259,15700019,15700186,15700190,15700256,15700259,15700262,15700265)) lists the Kimchi monsters. The one below ("Bachu") looks canine, not really a wolf, though.

[image: big dog-like creature]

I can't seem to find the episodes online nor much about the anime actually, even with Google queries centered about the original title (채채퐁 김치퐁), so I can't confirm the warrior woman. Have the (catchy!) opening instead:

Comment: You are the best , honestly i dont know how to thank you , i have been looking for this for about 6-7 years

Comment: @MAA glad to have helped! I hope you find the episodes somewhere :)

Comment: unfortunately the episodes aren't available anywhere , but iam glad that i at least remember its name now , thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [*Xam'd: Lost Memories*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Xam%27d:_Lost_Memories_episodes) (2008):

> Akiyuki, now nameless, has his face covered by the Xam'd mask once again. Nakiami has completed the ritual, returning the sky to its brightness and reviving those who were encased in stone. Refusing to accept Nakiami's fate, Yango attempts to keep the chamber from closing. Akiyuki, who falls from the sky and lands besides Yango, partially transforms into Xam'd and uses all his strength to try and keep the chamber door from closing, but to no avail. His exertion subsequently turns him into stone. The crew of the Zanbani drop letters over the area in hopes of bringing smiles to the people. Nine years later on Sentan Island, all of its inhabitants are peacefully continuing on with their lives. Akiyuki reawakens, as he reunites with the one he loves.