# Anime/cartoon where a kid has to save his grandma that turned to stone

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

Anime/cartoon where a kid has to save his grandma that turned to stone, and has to save her by getting all the "types" of creatures which help him fight.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This question needs more details; please check out the [suggestions for good ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/101407) and see if they help you remember anything else you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: This is quite brief can you remember anything else about it plot wise? Why was the grandma turned to stone? What was he fighting to save her? Why did he need the creatures? When did you watch this? Do you know what channel it was on? If you remember anything else you can [edit] those details into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly *Chaechaepong Kimchipong*, a 2002 Korean anime, as per my answer to [Old cartoon where villain turns villagers into statues](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/216362/).

> In the most peaceful village on Earth, Singleland, **a boy named Tochi lives a normal life with his grandmother. One day, all the creatures that lived in their land are suddenly petrified**, leaving Tochi as the lone survivor.
>
> Bewildered and frightened, Tochi meets a travelling little witch named Milo who informs him that what happened to his village, and many other villages including her own was due to the curse of the Black Mage Army. She reveals that he wasn't petrified because he had the magical Kimchi Stalks, therefore she gives him the "Chae Chong", a summoning tool, which only the person with Kimchi Stal can own. The "Chae Chong" can summon a Kimchi Pong when you put a Kimchi Stall, a powerful magical creature, which they use to fight the Black Army.

The grandmother turned to stone is here, as is the "collect monsters and use them ot fight" trope, and the earlier question mentions the main character lifting the curse:

> They defeat the main villain and turns all the villagers back to normal, there is a girl too that tags along with him...